# How do I properly connect to SQL Server 2014 database through SqlClient / SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, sqlclient

I am converting a Java application to .NET and C# and I am in the process of moving away from JDBC to `SqlClient`. I'm testing the database connection and it's failing due to one of the 2 errors shown below (sometimes it's the one, sometimes it's the other):

```
//Debug info
Loading filename: BREConfig.txt
Loading properties from file: BREConfig.txt
Properties Loaded: 23
Setting Config Values...
Server=tcp:###;Initial Catalog=Wc3Online;User ID=####;Password=####;TrustServerCertificate=True; Encrypt=False;
```

Error

> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=13952; handshake=1056;

```
//Debug info
Loading filename: BREConfig.txt
Loading properties from file: BREConfig.txt
Properties Loaded: 23
Setting Config Values...
Server=tcp:####;Initial Catalog=###;User ID=####;Password=###;TrustServerCertificate=True; Encrypt=False;
```

Error

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

I am able successfully connect to the database through RDC using SQL Server authentication as shown here:

[image: SQL Server connection ui]

[image: object connection here]

I have some code using `SqlClient` that connects to this database server:

```
SqlConnection testConn = BREDBConnectionUtil.GetConnection();
Console.WriteLine(BREDBConnectionUtil.GetConnectionString());  

try
{
    testConn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Database server connected, using " + testConn.Database);
    testConn.Close();
    Console.ReadLine(); 
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

```
// connection string values pulled from text file and stored in objects
private static SqlConnection con = new();
private static readonly BREConfiguration config = BRESession.GetConfiguration();
private static readonly Logger logger = new();

// Connect to SQL Server 2014
private static readonly string connectionString = "Server=tcp:" + config.GetDbConnection() + ";Initial Catalog=" + config.GetDbName() + ";User ID=" + config.GetDbUser() + ";Password=" + config.GetDbPassword() + ";TrustServerCertificate=True; Encrypt=False;";

// returns a SqlConnection to connect to SQL Server 2014 database
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    con.ConnectionString = connectionString;      

    try 
    {
        if (con.ConnectionString.Length == 0) 
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //print err
    } 

    return con;
}
```

Comment: I have never seen the `Server` parameter be used in the `Server=tcp:###` way. Also avoid long running connections (aka `private static SqlConnection con`).

Comment: @Cleptus yes the 'tcp:' was just a result of me doing a bunch of googling and trying various solutions. Although it didnt really change anything. In reality this is my first time working with c# and SqlClient. But that does make sense to avoid long running connections I'll alter that part

Comment: Check the logs on the server, there should be a "Severity=X, State=Y" in there somewhere.  That state code can tell you why something failed in the pre-login handshake.

Comment: The log info blocks out the connection details. While this is good and proper for the credentials, it would be nice to be able to see here that the server and database values in the connection string match the values from the screen shot.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn What values in the screenshot are censored in the post text? (My company blocks imgur and i didnt save the images)

Comment: @cuzzo The server name. The screenshot shows a partial name, but the error message only shows hash marks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the full DB server name is `LWCPWC3VSQL01\WC301,12503`

Comment: That comma is probably throwing something off

Comment: The bit after the comma is the port number which should be OK in the connection string  Example: "server=MyServer,1234;database=myDatabase;integrated security=true; " default port is I believe 1433 and would not need to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

The connection string should look like this:

```
//Connect to SQL Server 2014
 private static readonly string connectionString = $"Server={config.GetDbConnection()};Initial Catalog={config.GetDbName()};User ID={config.GetDbUser()};Password={config.GetDbPassword()}";
```

You probably don't want to specify `tcp:` at the front of the string for the SqlClient provider. Also,
`Encrypt=False` is already the default, and if you are not doing encryption (why not?), you don't need to trust any server certificates.

---

One other important thing to understand with database connections is the C# ADO.Net API does connection pooling for you as part of the provider. This means you should NOT try to create and re-use one connection object in your app. Rather, it really is better (a LOT better) to create and promptly dispose a new connection object for most queries... ideally as part of a `using` block.

With that in mind the `GetConnection()` method should look more like this:

```
public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

No need to over-think it. You'll generally have higher-level code handling exceptions already anyway, and giving yourself a new object each time also means you don't have to worry about synchronization anymore.

---

We could then test the connection like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(BREDBConnectionUtil.GetConnectionString());  
using var testConn = BREDBConnectionUtil.GetConnection();
            
try
{
    testConn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine($"Databse Server Connected, using {testConn.Database}");
    // no need to call .Close(). 
    // The using directive takes care of it automatically **and more safely**
    // at the end of the scope block
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
}
// but if you DO want to call .Close() manually, or not have a using directive, 
// it should be HERE, as part of a finally block
// (hint: this was true in Java, too)
Console.ReadLine();
```

But again: this is only a test. Since we create a new connection object for each query, there's not a lot of point in testing or opening the connection up front.

Comment: Also usually the default sql server installation does not enable remote connections by default, so a local connection could work but a remote connection would not. Nice pooling advice ;-)

Comment: Very informational, Id +1 if I had more reputation. But I seem to still be getting the same errors when testing the connection.

Comment: @cuzzo hmm. One thought: we can see the server is using a named instance. Are we sure the `\` character is included in the string correctly, and not being processed as an escape character? Also, that no extraneous whitespace, unicode byte order marks, etc, have made their way into the string?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Im not sure what you mean by `` character. If you mean the double quote ending/beginning the string, I dont tihnk its the issue given Im printing the connection string.  That character doesnt exist in the server value

Comment: @cuzzo I meant a backslash. I forget the comments are weird about code formatting sometimes.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I dont think so. Because the issue persists if I were to connect through  `Tools > Connect To Database`

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be an incompatibility with security protocols. Our SQL Server uses TLS 1.2 and my laptop I am trying to connect with uses TLS 1.3.

My guess is that the TCP handshake is successful while the TLS handshake is failing, and SQL server is being blamed for it resulting in a TCP error, `(provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)`

It will require further testing to be sure though.